# Do .ci domains have more frequent DNS issues than other domains?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, hosting

The .ci domain extension has been very unreliable over the weekend:

[outage of gouv.ci website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZO3S.png)

Does anybody have data or an idea of how often such outages have happened in the past?

We are planning to build an international business with a .ci domain and we are wondering if we should choose a more frequent domain such as .com or .org.

```
$ dig ci. NS | fgrep FAIL
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 27830


$(for NS in $(dig +short . NS | sort); do dig @"$NS" +noall +authority +norecurse ci. NS; done) | sort | uniq -c | sort -bnr
     13 ci.                     172800  IN      NS      phloem.uoregon.edu.
     13 ci.                     172800  IN      NS      ns.nic.ci.
     13 ci.                     172800  IN      NS      ns-ci.afrinic.net.
     13 ci.                     172800  IN      NS      ci.hosting.nic.fr.
     13 ci.                     172800  IN      NS      any.nic.ci.
$ eval dig +noall +answer +nottl {{any.nic,ns.nic}.ci.,phloem.uoregon.edu.,ci.hosting.nic.fr.,ns-ci.afrinic.net.}\ A{,AAA}
phloem.uoregon.edu.     IN      A       128.223.32.35
phloem.uoregon.edu.     IN      AAAA    2001:468:d01:20::80df:2023
ci.hosting.nic.fr.      IN      A       192.134.0.49
ci.hosting.nic.fr.      IN      AAAA    2001:660:3006:1::1:1
ns-ci.afrinic.net.      IN      A       196.216.168.30
ns-ci.afrinic.net.      IN      AAAA    2001:43f8:120::30
$ for NS in phloem.uoregon.edu. ci.hosting.nic.fr. ns-ci.afrinic.net.; do echo "::::: $NS :::::"; dig @"$NS" +noall +authority +comments +norecurse nic.ci. NS | grep -e FAIL -i -e '^nic\.ci\.'; done
::::: phloem.uoregon.edu. :::::
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 17974
::::: ci.hosting.nic.fr. :::::
nic.ci.                 7200    IN      NS      ns2.desec.org.
nic.ci.                 7200    IN      NS      ns1.desec.io.
::::: ns-ci.afrinic.net. :::::
nic.ci.                 7200    IN      NS      ns1.desec.io.
nic.ci.                 7200    IN      NS      ns2.desec.org.
$ for NS in ns1.desec.io. ns2.desec.org.; do echo "::::: $NS :::::"; eval dig @"$NS" +noall +answer +nottl {any.nic,ns.nic}.ci.\ A{,AAA}; done
::::: ns1.desec.io. :::::
any.nic.ci.             IN      A       204.61.216.120
any.nic.ci.             IN      AAAA    2001:500:14:6120:ad::1
ns.nic.ci.              IN      A       196.49.0.84
::::: ns2.desec.org. :::::
any.nic.ci.             IN      A       204.61.216.120
any.nic.ci.             IN      AAAA    2001:500:14:6120:ad::1
ns.nic.ci.              IN      A       196.49.0.84
$ for NSIP in 128.223.32.35 192.134.0.49 196.49.0.84 196.216.168.30 204.61.216.120 2001:468:d01:20::80df:2023 2001:500:14:6120:ad::1 2001:660:3006:1::1:1 2001:43f8:120::30; do echo "::::: $NSIP :::::"; dig @"$NSIP" +norecurse +noall +authority +additional +comments gouv.ci. NS | awk '{if(($0 ~ /FAIL/) || ($4 ~ /^(NS|A|AAAA)$/))print;}'; done
::::: 128.223.32.35 :::::
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 44883
::::: 192.134.0.49 :::::
gouv.ci.                7200    IN      NS      n2.sndi.ci.
gouv.ci.                7200    IN      NS      ns1.sndi.ci.
gouv.ci.                7200    IN      NS      ns3.sndi.ci.
gouv.ci.                7200    IN      NS      ns4.sndi.ci.
ns4.sndi.ci.            7200    IN      A       77.68.50.56
ns3.sndi.ci.            7200    IN      A       164.160.41.43
ns1.sndi.ci.            7200    IN      A       164.160.41.41
::::: 196.49.0.84 :::::
gouv.ci.                7200    IN      NS      ns4.sndi.ci.
gouv.ci.                7200    IN      NS      ns3.sndi.ci.
gouv.ci.                7200    IN      NS      n2.sndi.ci.
gouv.ci.                7200    IN      NS      ns1.sndi.ci.
ns1.sndi.ci.            7200    IN      A       164.160.41.41
ns3.sndi.ci.            7200    IN      A       164.160.41.43
ns4.sndi.ci.            7200    IN      A       77.68.50.56
::::: 196.216.168.30 :::::
gouv.ci.                7200    IN      NS      ns1.sndi.ci.
gouv.ci.                7200    IN      NS      ns3.sndi.ci.
gouv.ci.                7200    IN      NS      ns4.sndi.ci.
gouv.ci.                7200    IN      NS      n2.sndi.ci.
ns1.sndi.ci.            7200    IN      A       164.160.41.41
ns3.sndi.ci.            7200    IN      A       164.160.41.43
ns4.sndi.ci.            7200    IN      A       77.68.50.56
::::: 204.61.216.120 :::::
gouv.ci.                7200    IN      NS      n2.sndi.ci.
gouv.ci.                7200    IN      NS      ns3.sndi.ci.
gouv.ci.                7200    IN      NS      ns1.sndi.ci.
gouv.ci.                7200    IN      NS      ns4.sndi.ci.
ns4.sndi.ci.            7200    IN      A       77.68.50.56
ns3.sndi.ci.            7200    IN      A       164.160.41.43
ns1.sndi.ci.            7200    IN      A       164.160.41.41
::::: 2001:468:d01:20::80df:2023 :::::
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 5901
::::: 2001:500:14:6120:ad::1 :::::
gouv.ci.                7200    IN      NS      ns1.sndi.ci.
gouv.ci.                7200    IN      NS      n2.sndi.ci.
gouv.ci.                7200    IN      NS      ns4.sndi.ci.
gouv.ci.                7200    IN      NS      ns3.sndi.ci.
ns4.sndi.ci.            7200    IN      A       77.68.50.56
ns3.sndi.ci.            7200    IN      A       164.160.41.43
ns1.sndi.ci.            7200    IN      A       164.160.41.41
::::: 2001:660:3006:1::1:1 :::::
gouv.ci.                7200    IN      NS      ns4.sndi.ci.
gouv.ci.                7200    IN      NS      ns1.sndi.ci.
gouv.ci.                7200    IN      NS      n2.sndi.ci.
gouv.ci.                7200    IN      NS      ns3.sndi.ci.
ns4.sndi.ci.            7200    IN      A       77.68.50.56
ns3.sndi.ci.            7200    IN      A       164.160.41.43
ns1.sndi.ci.            7200    IN      A       164.160.41.41
::::: 2001:43f8:120::30 :::::
gouv.ci.                7200    IN      NS      ns1.sndi.ci.
gouv.ci.                7200    IN      NS      ns3.sndi.ci.
gouv.ci.                7200    IN      NS      ns4.sndi.ci.
gouv.ci.                7200    IN      NS      n2.sndi.ci.
ns1.sndi.ci.            7200    IN      A       164.160.41.41
ns3.sndi.ci.            7200    IN      A       164.160.41.43
ns4.sndi.ci.            7200    IN      A       77.68.50.56
$ for NSIP in 77.68.50.56 164.160.41.41 164.160.41.43; do dig @"$NSIP" +noall +answer +norecurse www.gouv.ci. A | sed -e 's/$/'"; $NSIP/"; done
www.gouv.ci.            14400   IN      A       164.160.41.94; 77.68.50.56
www.gouv.ci.            14400   IN      A       164.160.41.94; 164.160.41.41
www.gouv.ci.            14400   IN      A       164.160.41.94; 164.160.41.43
$ dig @ci.hosting.nic.fr. +noall +authority +additional sndi.ci. NS
sndi.ci.                7200    IN      NS      ns4.sndi.ci.
sndi.ci.                7200    IN      NS      ns1.sndi.ci.
sndi.ci.                7200    IN      NS      ns2.sndi.ci.
sndi.ci.                7200    IN      NS      ns3.sndi.ci.
ns4.sndi.ci.            7200    IN      A       77.68.50.56
ns3.sndi.ci.            7200    IN      A       164.160.41.43
ns2.sndi.ci.            7200    IN      A       164.160.41.42
ns1.sndi.ci.            7200    IN      A       164.160.41.41
$
eval dig @164.160.41.41 +noall +answer +norecurse n{s1,{,s}2,s3,s4}.sndi.ci.\ A{,AAAA} | sort -u
n2.sndi.ci.             14400   IN      CNAME   ns2.sndi.ci.
ns1.sndi.ci.            14400   IN      A       164.160.41.41
ns2.sndi.ci.            14400   IN      A       164.160.41.42
ns3.sndi.ci.            14400   IN      A       164.160.41.43
ns4.sndi.ci.            14400   IN      A       77.68.50.56
$ for NSIP in 164.160.41.42; do dig @"$NSIP" +noall +answer +norecurse www.gouv.ci. A | sed -e 's/$/'"; $NSIP/"; done
www.gouv.ci.            14400   IN      A       164.160.41.94; 164.160.41.42
$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The availability of a domain depends on the availability of the (root) **DNS servers of that Country Code TLD domain** and the **domains own  DNS servers** and zone data.

Your screenshot doesn't  conclusively point to what DNS server(s) behaved problematically, the CC TLD nameservers (`ns.nic.ci.` and friends) or the domain specific ones for the gouv.ci domain (`ns[1-4].sndi.ci.`) .

So equating the availability of one domain and their own name servers with the overall availability of the complete CC TLD might be also be jumping to the wrong conclusion.

---

With only less than 20'000 registered domain names (current status according to https://www.nic.ci/) they are a relatively small  CC top level domain.

In my opinion, compared to the size of the country and population, that also appears a really small number and suggests that even most organisations in   Côte d'Ivoire targeting locals don't use the .ci domain either.

So unless you have a really cute brand name in mind, that doesn't yet inspire a lot of confidence if that will be the best choice, regardless of how capable the .CI TLD is or isn't run.

---

An outage of, or a successful attack against, a TLD will effectively take out all domains in that TLD  so those TLD root servers need to be stable, have good (global) connectivity and be resistant to for example large DDOS attacks. That is a large responsibility and takes special expertise and usually a lot of resources,  which is why some CC and other TLD operators pool resources and others make use of the technical expertise and resources of for example a registry service provider (RSP).

I do not know how the .CI  Côte d'Ivoire CC TLD is operated. But with less than 20'000 registered domains I imagine resources are tight regardless.